# Transfer raw data into optimized MySQL table: algorithm to detect correct data type?

Tags: php, mysql

I am importing a raw txt file to MySQL and need an algorithm to detect the correct MySQL data type after scanning each column of data. Can anyone suggest an existing PHP library to accomplish this task?

The algorithm would have the following features:

- scan each record in a column and assign the correct type, for example...

  - "-30021" -> SMALLINT
  - "foo bar" -> CHAR(7)
- aggregate all types in the column to select the type that has complete coverage.
- settings to allow for more conservative vs. relaxed type detection. (If 98% of values are integers, and there are a few strings, we'll reject the strings as noise, and use an INT data type.)
- After all columns have been detected, automate the MySQL table creation and data import.
- Scripting & reports

Thanks for your tips

Comment: Is this a one-off type thing, or will you regularly be importing random/arbitrary formatted files?

Comment: Sounds like you've already got it figured out - now get coding!  But seriously, no, I've never heard of any libraries like that (at least for PHP).

Comment: I'm not aware of an existing library, but shouldn't be a hard challenge to make this yourself?

Comment: Marc B: this is something that would be part of a web-services main workflow, so it should be optimized and stable.  Since it's for production, wanted to see if there was an existing tool.

Comment: Chris: Have you heard of something like this in another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has this functionality built in! It's called [`PROCEDURE ANALYSE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/procedure-analyse.html)

I wrote about it in a blog post I wrote last September: [What makes a good MySQL index? Part 1: Column Size](http://webmonkeyuk.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/what-makes-a-good-mysql-index-part-1-column-size/)

Comment: holy! I should have known about that. reading your blog post now, which is very helpful. many thanks.